# Force old revision to the current revision

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I made a boo boo with a with a Visual Studio 2010 project on TFS2010, and instead of spending hours trying to fix it did i decide just to go 2 revisions back, and continue from there, which worked fine.
But how can i now make my local version the current revision? When i try to commit i just get a version mismatch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the pending changes conflicts dialog:

Top Menu -> View -> Other Windows -> Pending Changes

If you want to make your local version the current version.  You will be presented with a list of conflicts.

For every conflict select: "Keep Local Version"

Here is an example of what your screen will look like notice the "Keep Local Version" option to the right of the item in question.

[image]

Check it in and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You check everything out with your local copies and during check-in you will encounter conflicts. You will resolve them by overwriting server version and accepting your local copies.

Voila, your local copies are latest now.